# insert url in footer

Tags: header-footer

I would like to insert a url in a footer but that doesn't working.

I use the following code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\lfoot{\href{www.xyz.com}}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}
hi
\end{document}
```

instead of url it shows the blank space

Comment: Use `\lfoot{\url{www.xyz.com}}`

Comment: You do not need the package "url" if you are loading hyperref.

Answer (score 4):

`\href` has two arguments `{URL}{Text}`:

```
\lfoot{\href{www.xyz.com}{my URL}}
```